# Amcharts 4 : Disable single legend item programmatically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amcharts, amcharts4

I just need to know how to disable a single legend item programmatically on chart reload (***disable** means: legend is shown greyed out and its linked curve is hidden*), as I need to reload a chart with some new data using some back and forward arrows, but still need to remember the user preference or the state of legend items (on/off)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks [@xorspark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6106614/xorspark) that's really it, it's about controlling the series not legend.

It happened to work specifically with the `appeared` or `inited` events, not `shown` event as it seemed to be, like this:

```
series.events.on("inited", () => {
  reactState ? series.show() : series.hide();
});
```

`inited` event even works better, as disabled legends will not show a glimpse of their color on the curve when using `appeared`.

Answer (score 1):

You can just call [`hide`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/series/#hide_method) on the series associated with that legend marker to hide the series/grey out the marker:

```
series.hide();
```